# Enzyme: Test children rendering failling with mount but passes with shallow

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme + Jest to test some React components.

I have the following test:

```js
describe('<Modal />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  it('should render children props', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Modal />);
    wrapper.setProps({
      children: <div className='should-render'>This should be rendered</div>
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.should-render').length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

And it works just find. But, if I replace the `shallow` method from `enzyme` with `mount` the test fails (can't find a element with `.should-render` class).

Is this the expected behavior? I though that the difference between `shallow` and `mount` was the ability to access lifecycle methods but render worked the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So the problem was my lack of understanding of how `mount` works.

My `Modal` component has a state variable called `show` that prevents the element from mounting if it's set to `false` (I'm wrapping `react-boostrap` modal component, that has this beahavior). By default, this state variable it's false and since the children are being rendered in the body of the modal, no children were found because the element wasn't beign mounted.